# Meu JavaScript parou de passar as variáveis quando utilizo URL Amigável

Tags: javascript, url-amigável

Utilizo o seguinte JavaScript, e o mesmo parou de passar as variáveis pelos parâmetros quando utilizei URL Amigável.

Como por exemplo `cidade='+$('#cidades').val()` deixou de pegar o valor da variável.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var idcl = document.getElementById('idcl').value;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#estados').change(function(){
                $('#cidades').load('cidades.php?estado='+$('#estados').val()+'&cliente='+idcl);
            });
            $('#cidades').change(function(){
                $('#negocios').load('negocio.php?cidade='+$('#cidades').val()+'&cliente='+idcl+'&estados='+$('#estados').val());
            });
            $('#negocios').change(function(){
                $('#tipos').load('tipo.php?negocio='+$('#negocios').val()+'&cidade='+$('#cidades').val()+'&cliente='+idcl+'&estados='+$('#estados').val());
            });
            $('#tipos').change(function(){
                $('#dormitorios').load('dormitorios.php?tipo='+$('#tipos').val()+'&cliente='+idcl);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Precisa ser mais claro na sua pergunta, os valores vêm por meio de GET e são guardados em campos input hidden? Qual a regra htaccess imposta ? Nada disso está na pergunta e o problema se você relata que é com a url amigável não deve estar neste trecho de código postado.

Answer (score -1):

Tente passar como template string:
[Template string - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

Abra uma string com

> `

Dentro do template chame com

> ${variavel}

Ficaria algo do tipo:

```
$('#cidades').load(`cidades.php?estado=${('#estados').val()}&cliente=${idcl}`);
```